# Bot Emulator connected to Node.js service on a different machine

Tags: node.js, botframework, ngrok

I have a Node.js service running Bot Builder code on a Linux desktop.
I have a MSFT Bot Emulator running on my Mac, which is in the same corp network as the desktop.

I cannot get the bot emulator to connect to the Node.js service for callbacks. I have ngrok v2.1.18 installed and the emulator (app settings) has ngrok path configured; but I keep getting an error message that I need to configure ngrok for callback URL.

From the Bot Emulator logs, `ngrok` fails to start with this error:

> Failed to start ngrok: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used ngrok but I find a hacking solution.

Open file `botframework-emulator.app/Contents/Resources/app/app/server/botFrameworkService.js` and change:

```
this.localhostServiceUrl = `http://localhost:${port};
```

to:

```
const hostname = os.hostname();
this.localhostServiceUrl = `http://${hostname}:${port}`;
```

Don't forget to import `os` module:

`const os = require("os");`

Comment: Nice hack, but would like to see a better solution that will work across SDK upgrades :)